# is there any way to make push-down content navbar with bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

please refer "https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbBPPY" i want same result but instead of using bootstrap-3, i want to use bootstrap-4.
U can see the code in the reference link "https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbBPPY"

HTML

````
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
        <li class="nav-link active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="menu-trigger">Drop-Down Menu<i class="fa fa-angle-down flipped"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu">
            <li class="nav-link">
              <a href="#" class="m-pub"><i class="fa fa-microphone fa-2x"></i>Option</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link">
              <a href="" class="m-pub"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-2x"></i>Option</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container" style="background: red;height:100px; width: 100%;">
</div>```
````

Comment: What's the difference between two? Provide detail as well as what have you tried and what issues are your facing?

Comment: I tried the same code with bootstarp 4 but instead of pushing down content the dropdown overlay on red container but i want if someone click on dropdown it will push the red container down.